# VBA Macros to insert a row at the end of a table, then paste values of previously copied lines in a specific range of the new row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for help on a VBA Macros. This is my current code. Where the **** are I need some code to insert a row at the end of the table on the active worksheet, and then paste the values copied in the above code with the range of ("E1:R8") into the range (E?:R?") of the newly created row.

```vb
Sub Workbook()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RFP Form").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataHelperSheet").Copy After:=wb.Sheets(1)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    wb.SaveAs "Z:\Temp\test3.xlsx"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="Z:\Temp\" & Range("I1").Value

    Worksheets("DataHelperSheet").Activate
    Range("E1:R8").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Workbooks("Proposal Quote Master List(LB).xlsm").Activate
    Worksheets("Master List").Activate
    '***

    Range("E1:R298").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the last row in a table by using this after you've selected the first cell in the table: (Try it like this)

```
Range("E1").Columns.End(xlDown).Offset(1,0).EntireRow.Insert
```

Or you can paste the data with:

```
.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

You should look at [ExcelCampus](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/copy-paste-cells-vba-macros/) and this stack overflow question [How to insert copied cells instead of paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25824116/excel-macro-vba-how-to-insert-copied-cells-instead-of-paste)

Above should give you all you need to do what you are asking for.

Comment: Thank you, but how would I paste the data that was copied?

Comment: See my edit - please mark the question as solved if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't name your sub `Workbook` it is a reserved word because VBA uses this for worbook objects (see at `Dim wb As Workbook`) and this can be very confusing for humans and VBA.
2. Don't mix `ThisWorkbook` and `ActiveWorkbook` and avoid using `Activate`, `ActiveWorkbook` and `.Select`. `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook the code is written in (it never changes. `ActiveWorkbook` is the workbook that has focus (is on top) and it can easily change by a single mouse click (therefore it is not a very reliable reference). Instead always try to use a fix reference like you did with `wb.SaveAs`.
3. Make sure **all** your `Range` objects have a workbook and worksheet specified. If you write `Range("I1").Value` VBA does not definitely know which workbook or worksheet you mean. It guesses you mean the active ones. But again this is not very reliable because this can change by a single mouse click. Make sure you tell VBA **exactly** what you mean by using something like `wb.Workbooks("Sheet1").Range("I1").Value` so there is no room for VBA to start guessing.
4. Stop using `.Select`. Instead of

   ```
    Worksheets("DataHelperSheet").Activate
    Range("E1:R8").Select
    Selection.Copy
   ```

   just write

   ```
    wb.Worksheets("DataHelperSheet").Range("E1:R8").Copy
   ```

   again specify the workbook `wb` if working with more than one workbook.
5. To find the last used cell in column E for example use

   ```
    wsMasterList.Cells(wsMasterList.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)
   ```

   and use `.Offset(RowOffset:=1)` to move one row down to the next empty cell to paste at.

So you end up with something like:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub CreateWorkbook()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RFP Form").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataHelperSheet").Copy After:=wb.Sheets(1)
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.SaveAs "Z:\Temp\test3.xlsx"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    wb.SaveAs Filename:="Z:\Temp\" & wb.Workbooks("SPECIFY YOUR SHEET").Range("I1").Value '‹~~ specify sheet name

    wb.Worksheets("DataHelperSheet").Range("E1:R8").Copy
    
    Dim wsMasterList As Worksheet
    Set wsMasterList = Workbooks("Proposal Quote Master List(LB).xlsm").Worksheets("Master List")

    wsMasterList.Cells(wsMasterList.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(RowOffset:=1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```